# How to do a linear model in R?

Tags: r, regression

The objective of this research was to investigate the long-term effects of irrigation with treated waste water on some chemical soil properties.

The investigation was carried out by comparison of soil properties in two different fields: one irrigated with the effluent from Parkan Waste water Treatment Plant over a period of six years, and the other one irrigated with water over the same period of time. Soil samples were taken from different depths of 0-15, 15-30, 30-60, 60-100 and 100-150 cm in both fields, and analyzed for various chemical properties.

For visual summaries, I am going to plot depths of soil and element (with line and bar plots). However, I also need to fit a linear model with one categorical and one continuous predictor. How can this be done in R?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is actually absurdly simple:

```
mymodel <- lm(dependentvariable ~ continuousvariable + categoricalvariable,    
              data=yourdata).
```

You can then call `summary()` to get the coefficients, and `plot()` to examine the residuals. 
HTH.

Comment: In this particular case, I think it would be best to further clarify the R syntax and meaning of `summary` and `plot`, or to give external links that help to understand how to interpret LM output in R. Maybe John Maindonald or Peter Dalgaard's tutorials, or directly the CRAN contrib docs?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to enter your data into R, see [this class note](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/notes/entering.htm). You can follow the steps of [this tutorial](http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html) in the analysis, section 4.4 has a very similar example. In visualization you could do something similar as the `qplot(wt, mpg, data = mtcars, colour = factor(cyl))` example of [this tutorial](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_point.html).

Comment: Even though you link to the help page, I'd probably put a `library(ggplot2)` before qplot as that code will not run in a fresh R session w/o loading the appropriate package.